# Procedurally Generated Variable Naming

Tags: javascript

So I am currently attempting to procedurally generate variable names based on some other things I want to do later in the function.

However when I attempt this as a trial function:

```
var gridCoord = [[1,2]];

var 'run' + gridCoord[0][0] + gridCoord[0][1] = function() {
    console.log("Success!");
}

run12();
```

I am receiving syntax errors in the console.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. You really don't want to do that. You could use an object though.

Comment: And my advice, don't take the quick answers that say to do it in `window`, unless you want to pollute the global scope; this is just looking for trouble.

Comment: @elclanrs Dont worry, Im trying to stay as far away from global scope as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. Use dynamic naming of objects.

```
window['run'+gridCoord[0][0]+gridCoord[0][1]] = function() {
```

The window object is a global object; these functions can be called normally as any other global function can be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
window['run'+gridCoord[0][0]+gridCoord[0][1] ]= function(){
        console.log("Success!");
    }
```

In the global scope, all variables are children of the window property